# A Django QuerySet that always returns iterator()

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Is it possible to define a custom QuerySet, that will always return the output of `.iterator()` when it is iterated, while keeping all the other QuerySet functionality? Wrapping an existing QuerySet would work, too.

Currently, the only solution I came up with is this awful wrapper class:

```
class IteratorQuerySet:
    def __init__(self, qs):
        self._qs = qs

    def __iter__(self):
        return self._qs.iterator()

    def __getitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._qs.__getitem__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._qs, attr)
```

The downside is, that it is not really a QuerySet, but simply forwards all attributes and getitem calls to the qs.

What different angles could I try?